# c++ - recv() How to turn bytes back into message?

Tags: c++, client-server, send, winsock2, recv

So my code stores the resultant of recv() into an int var

```
int iResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
```

Which I send it

```
char *sendbuf = "this is a test That is longer then what it was";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int) strlen(sendbuf), 0);
```

So how do I make the bytes received back int a char string on the server side?

Comment: Append a null byte to it after receipt, or *send* the null byte, by specifying `strlen(sendbuf)+1`.

Comment: @EJP Do I need to cast recv() back into a string/char sting, or do I just need to make iResult a different type?

Comment: `recv` returns _how many_ bytes it has read. Your bytes are in your buffer.

Comment: Is this a TCP connection? If so, if you want to send and receive messages, you'll need to implement some kind of message protocol. TCP is a byte-stream protocol, not a message protocol.

Comment: You can either 1) send the string's byte count before sending the actual string, then have the receiver read the byte count and then read the specified number of bytes, or 2) delimit the string with a null character or other unique delimiter, and then have the receiver read bytes until it receives that delimiter.

Comment: aaahhh @RemyLebeau I see. I cout << recvbuf, and it did have the message but then the unknown asci char for about the number of bytes, so I would just put a null, have a loop that pulls the string out right? couldn't I also divide the number of bytes, because a char is 1 bit and  8 bytes to a bit? at any rate write that but in terms of recvbuf, and that should be the answer.

Comment: Bits has nothing to do with it. You have received `iResult` bytes (if it was positive), and you have to print and use exactly that many bytes from the buffer. `recvbuf[iResult] = 0` is one way; there are others.

Comment: `recv()` can return fewer bytes than requested. The **proper** way to handle this is to use a messaging protocol that is explicit in how individual messages are separated from each other, regardless of how many reads it takes to receive each message.

Comment: @EJP I got the string out, thank you, Sorry for any frustration, first time doing this and I am just happy that it is connecting, and sending info XD.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have no clue how to do that in code but with a loop, and the number of bytes I was able to get the string \('-')/, the protical is auto gotten from the server which I put my code on github at https://github.com/78Star/Mailer

Comment: Bare with me I am new to this, I am using tcp IPPROTO_TCP